# How would you write a set that contains all the reals for a solution and an empty set?

Tags: notation

My teacher wants me to write solution sets like: solution set $= \{x:x \in \mathbb{ℝ}, \}$, but he didn't go over how to write a set that contains all reals and how to write a set that is empty.

Comment: I'm confused, what's wrong with $\{x:x\in\Bbb R\}$? Is it not the set of all the reals?

Comment: I'm not sure because I just started set notation a few days ago

Comment: So does that mean {  :  ∈ ℝ} already means that the solutions are all real numbers?

Comment: It's the collection of exactly all the $x$ such that $x\in\Bbb R$, which turns out is exactly $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write the set that contains all reals as $\Bbb R$.

You write the empty set as $\emptyset$.

If your teacher insists on writing every set in the way that you say (although I can't think why they would want this), then you can write any set $A$ as

$$\{x:x\in A\}$$

In particular, you can take $A=\Bbb R$ or $A=\emptyset$ here.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

$\mathbb R= \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x =x \}$

$\emptyset= \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \neq x \}$